# Default transaction mode for create service of feathers-knex

Tags: feathersjs

I just figured out that creating multiple items with feathers-knex is not doing a transaction by default. But in our application we have to make sure that we always add all or nothing.
How can I make sure that create methods with an array as data is always wrapped in a transaction? Do I really have to add the transaction hook to all create methods in every service?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that is the case, yes. What's wrong with search and replace?